# SolidJS: Using createEffect to observe signal changes

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, single-page-application, solid-js

I have started a new journey with SolidJS after being in the *Angularverse* since Angular 2 :)
I've been following the [Effects tutorial](https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/introduction_effects) on their official website but I'm not able to make it work the way I want.

I thought `createEffect` would keep track and run every time the count signal changed, or so I understood from here:

> The effect automatically subscribes to any signal that is read during
> the function's execution and reruns when any of them change.

Unfortunately, clicking the button doesn't seem to have any effect. So, what am I missing?

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, createEffect } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
  const doubleCount = () => setCount(count() * 2);

  createEffect(() => {
    console.log("The count is now", count());
  });

  return <button onClick={doubleCount}>Click Me</button>;
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a feature !

What is happening is that 0 * 2 = 0 so it doesn't trigger any effect because the value of count didn't change.

Try

```js
const [count, setCount] = createSignal(1);
```

to see a console.log each time the value change with your click

Comment: I hate my life :D
I guess it was really late yesterday haha Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and runs as expected. Two possible reason why you don't see change:

- If there is no log, it means you don't have #app element on the page.
- If there is only one log but no subsequent ones, that is because 0*2 is 0, value does not change, so it does not trigger re-run.

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/7ec9c592-6c30-43a0-97a7-5f26917b4334